# How to store variable in url

Tags: javascript, variables

How do I store var x in the url instead of 5010979510?

```
var id = DigitalData[0].Products[0].ProductId

$('.iosSlider').before('<a href="https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest_redirect.php?id=5010979510&f=659" target="_blank"></a>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var id = DigitalData[0].Products[0].ProductId

$('.iosSlider').before('<a href="https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest_redirect.php?id=' + id + '&f=659" target="_blank"></a>');
```